# Right way to initialize backbone collection

Tags: backbone.js, collections

Having a model, it presumaly would be nice to use it in a collection. However I am a bit puzzled with the collections and colleciton initialization.

1. May be I am missing the idea of the collection itself. So probably the first question would be can we have a collection and then a have a instances of the collection?
2. Secondly, how do we create an instance of the collection?

So here is a snippet of my code:

Model:

```
CarInsuranceApp.Models.Row = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    id: null,
    ....
    higher_excess: null,
  }
});
```

Collection

```
CarInsuranceApp.Collections.Table = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: CarInsuranceApp.Models.Row,

  // my collection methods
  filter: function() {
  ...
```

Initialize collection

```
CarInsuranceApp.results = new CarInsuranceApp.Collections.Table( myArraOfObjects );
```

This gives back an output of:

```
child {models: Array[19], length: 19, _byId: Object, _idAttr: "id", _events: Object…}
```

So the question would be what is this thing `child`? Also an instance of the backbone.collection doesn't respond to methods, such as `where`, is there any way to call `super` methods?

Comment: 1. Yes and 2. Just like you did

Comment: Ok, I was missing `[]`, before `{` in Collections declaration